# Copy QTableWidget cell content to clipboard

Tags: c++, qt, clipboard

I built up a context menu that opens with right-click on the cell in a `QTableWidget`. Could you help me to create a command to copy the contents of that cell to the clipboard? The examples I have found on the web are really bad.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in the slot that connected to your menu action in the following way:

```
QClipboard *clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
clipboard->setText(tableItem->text());
```